# Connecting three screens to the same laptop wirelessly

Tags: hdmi, wireless, displays

Here's the thing I've got. There's a presentation going to happen in some restaurant. My boss wants to place some three screens (most probably some big LCD TVs) in different places of the big hall. But the restaurant doesn't allow to put wires through the hall. I know there are some wireless HDMI receivers and transmitters on the market. But I am not sure about their robustness. The only idea that came to my mind is to buy some HDMI hub and three pairs of these wireless HDMI, connect it to my MacBook and run it like that. That would work, I think, but that's not elegant at all + it's pretty expensive.

So my questions are:

1. What experience did you have with these wireless HDMI receivers and transmitters? What models can you recommend?
2. Any other ideas on how to solve the problem, rather than what I suggested?

Comment: Depending on what kind of content you're displaying and the synchronization requirements, you might be able to use one computer per monitor instead of multiple monitors for the same computer.

Comment: I have to make some computer screen mirroring there. I will be telling people about some website's features and show it to people there, making it interactive.

Answer (score 1):

If the wireless options do not work out, and you have access to more PCs, you could use a presentation software and connect to the presentation from the PCs hooked up to the other screens.

LogMeIn, Teamviewer, Microsoft Teams, Cisco Webex, Google Hangouts, Skype, ect.

Answer (score 0):

Wireless DisplayPort adapters such as [https://www.amazon.com/Wireless-DisplayPort-Display-Emulator-Fit-Headless/dp/B073YCMYNW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073YCMYNW) allow you to send a signal to monitor "A", and with DisplayPort monitors you can cable from monitor "A" to "B" and "B" to "C". "B" and "C" are mirrored to match what's on "A".